# Cannot add wiki page to Gitlab project - safe.directory not found

Tags: ubuntu, docker, gitlab

Trying to add first wiki page to my project on self-hosted Gitlab (docker container).
Appears error - `13:commit: open repository: config value 'safe.directory' was not found`.
Meantime commits for code passed successfully.

Try to set git:git ownership for /opt/gitlab/data - error still present.

Try to exec `git config --global -add safe.directory '*'` - error remains.